# How to insert the data that I am getting from a API in to ionic cards?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

So here is the thing I am getting cover art from a API now I want to put the img url in img src of my ionic card and then I want it to repeat the whole thing for each item in the array, if there is a angular shortcut to do this please tell me.

Here is my js

```
var discover = new XMLHttpRequest();
// variables end
discover.open('GET','https://api.deezer.com/chart');
discover.onload = function(){
var discoverdata = JSON.parse(discover.responseText);
console.log(discoverdata.tracks.data[3].album.cover_medium)
};
discover.send();
```

Here is my HTML

```
<ion-slides id="discover">
          <ion-slide>
              <ion-card class="discover-card">
                  <img class="cover" src={} alt="">
                </ion-card>
          </ion-slide>
```

Here is the data that the JSON api is returning

```
(10) […]
​
0: Object { id: 698905582, title: "Señorita", title_short: "Señorita", … }
​
1: Object { id: 648855322, title: "Old Town Road", title_short: "Old Town Road", … }
​
2: Object { id: 678017492, title: "I Don't Care", title_short: "I Don't Care", … }
​
3: Object { id: 703496412, title: "Beautiful People (feat. Khalid)", title_short: "Beautiful People (feat. Khalid)", … }
​
4: Object { id: 660051472, title: "Old Town Road (Remix)", title_short: "Old Town Road", … }
​
5: Object { id: 655095912, title: "bad guy", title_short: "bad guy", … }
​
6: Object { id: 623723282, title: "Piece Of Your Heart", title_short: "Piece Of Your Heart", … }
​
7: Object { id: 706719772, title: "Goodbyes", title_short: "Goodbyes", … }
​
8: Object { id: 684267022, title: "Cross Me (feat. Chance the Rapper & PnB Rock)", title_short: "Cross Me (feat. Chance the Rapper & PnB Rock)", … }
​
9: Object { id: 674016222, title: "Choir", title_short: "Choir", … }
​
length: 10
```

I want it to apply a different image for each card.

the first object in the JSON data

```
0: {…}
​​
album: {…}
​​​
cover: "https://api.deezer.com/album/100856872/image"
​​​
cover_big: "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/4426e8a06d8d0cd96263094c6178bbf9/500x500-000000-80-0-0.jpg"
​​​
cover_medium: "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/4426e8a06d8d0cd96263094c6178bbf9/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg"
​​​
cover_small: "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/4426e8a06d8d0cd96263094c6178bbf9/56x56-000000-80-0-0.jpg"
​​​
cover_xl: "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/4426e8a06d8d0cd96263094c6178bbf9/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg"
​​​
id: 100856872
​​​
title: "Señorita"
​​​
tracklist: "https://api.deezer.com/album/100856872/tracks"
​​​
type: "album"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
artist: Object { id: 5962948, name: "Shawn Mendes", link: "https://www.deezer.com/artist/5962948", … }
​​
duration: 190
​​
explicit_content_cover: 0
​​
explicit_content_lyrics: 0
​​
explicit_lyrics: false
​​
id: 698905582
​​
link: "https://www.deezer.com/track/698905582"
​​
position: 1
​​
preview: "https://cdns-preview-5.dzcdn.net/stream/c-58c2f2bd81ee0d60e70310831737a910-4.mp3"
​​
rank: 998970
​​
title: "Señorita"
​​
title_short: "Señorita"
​​
title_version: ""
​​
type: "track"
```

Thanks in advance :**{**)

Comment: what you getting in api image link or image

Comment: @ Nikhil Gangurde a link

Comment: @Rishi Not clear! do you want the single image to be iterate over *n* times?

Comment: @Rishi *I want it to apply a different image for each card.* Where that images will come? Random?

Comment: each object has a album array which has the cover image link.

Answer (score 0):

If your getting a link from json bind to src tag like shown below:

```
<ion-card class="discover-card" *ngFor="let data of discoverdata.tracks.data;let index = index">
         <img class="cover" src={{data?.cover_medium}} alt="">
        <div>{{item?.title}}</div>
</ion-card>
```

`data.img` contains a link of your image.
so If your image link is in discoverdata.tracks.data[3].album.cover_medium so bind that to src.

Comment: I framed my question wrong i also want it to repeat doing the same thing for all the items in the array

Comment: just put the above statement in for loop

Answer (score 0):

Note: don't put *ngIf and *ngFor on same javascript element.

`*ngFor iterates array of object`... same as `for` in javascript.

```
? checks for null or undefined values.
```

When Angular renders the view before project got a value assigned, it causes an exception. ?. stops evaluating when project is null or undefined, which usually happens when data is fetched async, for example from the server which can take quite some time.

The next time change detection recognizes a change, the bindings will be re-evaluated. When project then has a value it will bind project.category.

## Try:-

```
    let data = [  <==== your data, save in variable data
    {
    "album ":[{
       "cover_image_link":""
     }
    ]
    }
    ]

    <ng-container *ngIf="data">    
       <ion-card class="discover-card" *ngFor="let item of data;let index = index">
                 <img class="cover" src={{item?.album[0].cover_image_link}} alt="">
                <div>{{item?.title}}</div>
        </ion-card>
    </ng-container>

or,

 <ng-container *ngIf="data">    
       <ion-card class="discover-card" *ngFor="let item of data;let index = index">
 <ng-container  *ngFor="let itemm of item?.album;let indexx = index">  
                 <img class="cover" src={{itemm?.cover_image_link}} alt="">
   </ng-container>
                <div>{{item?.title}}</div>
        </ion-card>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: would you mind if I ask what does ngFor do and what is {{item.?.image}} in the src?

Comment: is there is image key in your objects.Fron where is your image.? show you json...atleast first object completely.

Comment: if your objects look  like what you posted and have...'cover' key then. updated answer.

Comment: thats not a key thats the album ID